# query to number the results fetched by a mysql query

Tags: mysql

i have a number of entries on every user id/user name . since all have different `id (auto inc)` i wanted to filter results adding a extra numbering such that when we use the following query

`select * from table_name where uid='4'`

then the results which are fetched would be like

```
uname  work   number

  4   paint     1

  4   cook      2
```

here the number column is which i wanted to arrange the fetched results accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the trick for doing this in MySQL, using a variable:

```
select t.*, @rn := @rn + 1 as number
from table_name t cross join (select @rn := 0) const
where uid='4'
```

Comment: btw how would is there a way to only get the value of cook number as if i put a where clause it recount the number for cook as 1

Comment: @user1001176 . . . You can put this query as a subquery and select "cook" in the outer query (if I understand your question).